# valores en matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo el siguiente código en python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_values = range(1, 1001)
y_values = [x ** 2 for x in x_values]
plt.style.use('seaborn-v0_8')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_values, y_values, s = 10)
ax.set_title("Square Numbers", fontsize = 24)
ax.set_xlabel("Value", fontsize = 10)
ax.set_ylabel("Square of value", fontsize = 10)
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', labelsize = 10)
ax.axis([0, 1000, 0, 1000000])
plt.show()
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: Resultado]

El problema es que en el eje Y siempre aparecen los valores en notación exponencial, como se ve. Como puedo hacer para que aparezcan "normales" (200000, 400000, etc)?

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Genial. Funcionó. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes indicar que el formato de las etiquetas es "plano" utilizando `ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')`

Ejemplo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = range(1, 1001)
y_values = [x ** 2 for x in x_values]
plt.style.use('seaborn-v0_8')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_values, y_values, s = 10)
ax.set_title("Square Numbers", fontsize = 24)
ax.set_xlabel("Value", fontsize = 10)
ax.set_ylabel("Square of value", fontsize = 10)
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', labelsize = 10)
ax.axis([0, 1000, 0, 1000000])
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
plt.show()
```

Esto produce:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]